# Exclude certain AD people in sharepoint 2010 search

Tags: search

How can I exclude people from a Sharepoint 2010 search based on an AD group that they are a member of?  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think, you would need to create a new profile field, which is populated from the AD sync. This would be their "Group". You can then filter the search with scopes.

There is as far as I know, no direct way of achieving this.